# Not able to edit a component inside another component in AEM editable templates

Tags: aem

I have an editable template. On the template, I am adding a component called 'contact us' which intern adds button component to the parsys. I am able to edit/configure the 'contact us' component but I am unable to edit/configure the button component which is added inside the 'contact us' component. It is not working on the editable template, but it works on the page level.

[image]

Comment: In the editable template you define the allowed components. By edit, you mean to configure some initial content?

Comment: This button component should not look like a parsys, nor have "lock" functionality to my knowledge. Can you share details about the button component itself?